# Generating Every possible Position Weight Matrix

Tags: r

I am trying to generate every potential position weight matrix keeping certain positions at 0.25 across all bases and others at 1. 
Something like:

```
1, 0 , 0.25, 1
0, 1 , 0.25, 0
0, 0 , 0.25, 0
0, 0 , 0.25, 0
```

to

```
1, 1 , 0.25, 1
0, 0 , 0.25, 0
0, 0 , 0.25, 0
0, 0 , 0.25, 0
```

and so forth for every possibility excluding the 0.25's column.

How would i go about this?

Comment: Hey Nilfws, I tried your function but it seems that the columns outside of the 0.25 are adding up to greater than 1.

Comment: hey NeilFws, that did work! can you explain how this function works! i cant seem to figure it out and i would lke to edit it